# What are the odds of getting a candy when feeding a defending Pokémon in a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

As some users have experienced, there is potential to receive a candy of the type corresponding to a Pokémon you feed in any of your team's gyms. This is especially useful to players who haven't been able to amass enough candy to evolve their Chansey or Dratini yet.

I have yet to personally get any candy this way, though, so this is clearly not a guarantee. What is the chance that I get a candy as a bonus for feeding a Pokémon in a gym?

Comment: While I have not done extensive research into this, I got my first candy around 200 berry feeds, creating a personal baseline of 1:200 chance for a candy, or 0.5%. I'll keep tracking to see if that average holds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the data produced by [this survey](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6jnvow/chance_of_getting_a_candy_for_feeding_berries/) for people to submit their personal experiences with candy received to Pokémon fed berries ratio, the rate at which a trainer will receive candies from feeding gym defenders berries is roughly **0.65%**.

> The current results are 0.65% chance, trainers received 66 candies while feeding 10151 times.