# Can I get candy for a Pokemon I haven't caught yet?

Tags: pokemon-go

Since you can [get candy for feeding Pokemon in gyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/311737/32055), I tend to favor feeding Pokemon for which I need candy over feeding my own Pokemon. These are generally Pokemon that I *have* caught, but haven't yet collected enough candy to evolve. Would this work for Pokemon I *haven't* caught yet, allowing me to get a jump start on collecting candy to evolve them once I do catch them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to receive candy when feeding berries to Pokémon you do not own. This is commonly referred to as “ghost candy” by users on reddit.

As seen in [this](https://reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6lh0wi/ghost_candy_received_after_catching_my_first/) reddit thread, a user details how they received candy for Snorlax despite never owning one. After they finally caught their first Snorlax, they had a total of 4 candy (3 non-pinap catch + 1 ghost candy)

Comment: Also note that if you transfer your last Pokemon of a specific type, and then catch/hatch/trade for a new one, you will still have your previous candy amount for that Pokemon type.